# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'firebase_options.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

please how can i solve this problem
Target of URI doesn't exist: 'firebase_options.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist

- I try this flutter clean
- flutter pub get
- restart

Comment: Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Can you please confirm if the issue is solved? if not, please provide the necessary information to solve the issue. Also go through [how to create a minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask good question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 7):

run `flutter pub add firebase_core` this is probably because you haven't installed firecore in your project yet

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the `firebase_options.dart` file is generated through `flutterfire configure` command.

Double check that you generate the file properly with the Flutterfire CLI and that you import it with the right path in your `main.dart` (or the file that require it)

Comment: I have installed firebase with CLl without error on my computer before. but this time i don't understand why i am getting errors

Comment: When I looked at the firebase console and saw that the project was created only for android, I did not care about ios. it was such a mistake. That's why I can't import it. 
                                **FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create ios udemy_firebase (ios) --bundle-id=com.example.udemy_firebase --json --project=udemy-firebase-c5ece 
ERROR: Failed to create iOS app for project udemy-firebase-c5ece. See firebase-debug.log for more info.**

Comment: Then, what's the error in the debug.log from firebase ?